# selecting (highlighting) the text of jdatechooser when focus gained

Tags: java, select, onfocus, jdatechooser

im looking for the line of code, which will select (highlight) the Date-text-string in the jDateChooser when it gets focused.

I read that I might have to do something like `.selectAll();`. but i cant get access to the textfield of the jDateChooser.

also `jDateChooser.selectOnFocus(true);` wont compile. NetBeans says: "cannot find symbol".
eventhough i have imported:

```
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import com.toedter.calendar.demo.DateChooserPanel;
```

any ideas anyone ?

Comment: there is JSpinner, JSpinner has Editor, there should be possible to select all, days, month or year, somewhere (maybe here too) must be solved this basic issue

Answer (score 1):

Change the library jar  for calendar few libraries do not have all the symbols.

You can [download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/JavaDateChooserComboBox.htm) from here and replace it with new one and then check:

Answer (score 0):

```
JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser(new Date());
dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
        ((JTextFieldDateEditor)evt.getSource()).selectAll();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent().addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter()    {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getSource() instanceof JTextComponent) {
                final JTextComponent textComponent=((JTextComponent)evt.getSource());
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        textComponent.selectAll();
                    }});
            }   
        }
    });
```